# Question regarding add_months function for previous month in SQL

Tags: oracle

Just have a quick question regarding the `ADD_MONTHS` function in when running an Oracle SQL query.
I know the following query will return: `28-FEB-22`

```
 SELECT
  LAST_DAY( ADD_MONTHS(sysdate , - 1 ))
FROM
  dual;

Result: 28-FEB-22
```

I have seen this query also but I'm not able to identify the purpose of `4,6)` numbers, this means it queries all the days of the previous month?

```
SELECT
  LAST_DAY(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1),4,6)
FROM
  dual;
```

Comment: The query you have seen will throw an error, since the LAST_DAY function only takes one argument, not three.Of course, it doesn't make sense to explain the "purpose" of two additional arguments that simply cause the query to throw an error. Note also that your first query, while valid, will return the last day of "last month" - with the time-of-day of the moment you run the query!!!

Comment: @OldProgrammer - the question is obviously about Oracle SQL (mentioned explicitly in the question, too) - why did you remove the only tag that was relevant to the question?

Comment: The second query returns `ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments` - so your question is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your help, I was able to confirm the following:

select distinct date_record from months where to_char(date_record,'MON-YY')= substr(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1),4,6) order by date_record desc

This gives a result of all the days of the previous month, from the first day to the last day of February. I will be using this to query data from the previous month and not only the last day of the previous month.